# How to create nested lists with random numbers?

Tags: python, loops, random, nested-lists

Please if you know how to solve this: I need to add nested lists, each list with randomly generated numbers, but within the same range. If I run my code like it is, it adds nested lists, each list with the correct length of 6 numbers, but the problem is that all numbers in the lists are identical! the output is like that:

```
[
    [27, 2, 23, 12, 9, 2, 28, 31],
    [27, 2, 23, 12, 9, 2, 28, 31],
    [27, 2, 23, 12, 9, 2, 28, 31],
    [27, 2, 23, 12, 9, 2, 28, 31]
]
```

How can I manage to generate new numbers each time I call the function in the for loop?

```
lottery_numbers = []
numbers_list = []

def num_generator():
   for num in range(0, 2):
      random_number = random.randint(1, 40)
      numbers_list.append(random_number)
      lottery_numbers.append(numbers_list)
  

for number in range(0, 4):
  num_generator()
```

Comment: Your function also has the very strange behavior of adding 2 new entries (in both `numbers_list` and `lottery_numbers`) each time it is run.  "correct length of 6 numbers" needs re-evaluation =).  Your displayed output doesn't match the code, it would be 8x8, not 4x8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you want 4 nested lists in one list each with a length of 6...

```
import random

x = [[random.randint(1,40) for i in range(6)] for i in range(4)]

print(x)
```

```
[
    [21, 41, 22, 14, 35, 0], 
    [13, 31, 25, 19, 35, 27], 
    [36, 29, 40, 37, 47, 49], 
    [12, 19, 5, 27, 48, 27]
]
```

Using a list comprehension we iterate 4 times, returning another randomly generated list (nested list comps)

Comment: no problem! if you liked the answer you can accept it for future users :). happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to keep your code as much as possible but i think this is what you intended to do.

```
import random

lottery_numbers = []


def num_generator():
    numbers_list = []
    for num in range(0, 6):
        random_number = random.randint(1, 40)
        numbers_list.append(random_number)
    lottery_numbers.append(numbers_list)
  

for number in range(0, 4):
    num_generator()


print (lottery_numbers)

[[39, 8, 3, 35, 20, 11], [30, 38, 37, 22, 18, 8], [24, 13, 3, 20, 15, 24], [33, 24, 2, 38, 9, 14]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! I've been learning Python only for 2 weeks so I still get things messed up )